# set object id from first array as a continuation to object id in second array

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I set `object id` in second `array` to be a continuation of last `object id` from previous (first) `array`?

```js
var quantities ={
  "Array1": [
    {
      //ID = 0
      "title": "Item",
      "price": 9.99
    },
    { 
      //ID = 1
      "title": "Item",
      "price": 19.99
    }
  ],
  "Array2": [
    {
      //ID = 0 <- I want this ID to be equal to last ID+1 from previous array
      "title": "Item",
      "price": 9.99
    }
  ]
 }
```

Comment: If you are talking about adding an `ID` property to the object, you can simply use a variable and precrement it as you go, `"ID": ++id`. But since you're not using property syntax for your ID's, I'm guessing you may be talking about array indexes? An array index is not an ID. The first element of an array will be the first element of that array regardless of the number of elements in another array. You could hack around it, but that would be an extreme code smell that will bite you eventually. If you want array index, use index. If you want ID's for your items, add an ID property.

Comment: Yeah, indeed, `array index` is the thing i meant. My bad there. Thanks for your advice. Will keep that in mind x)

Comment: Well, you *can* hack it. I.e. `var x = []; x[2] = 1;` will yield `x = [undefined, undefined, 1]`. That way, `x.push(2)` will be inserted at index `3`, but you'll have all kinds of side effects, such as `x.length` including the undefined items etc. Definitely not intended use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys()`, `Array.prototype.forEach()`

```
var n = 0;
Object.keys(quantities).forEach(function(obj) {
  quantities[obj].forEach(function(curr) {
    curr.ID = n;
    ++n
  })
});
```